# Windows .git repository on desktop

Tags: windows, git

In Windows 7, I turned on view hidden folders and saw a hidden .git repository on my desktop. I was cleaning things up, and thought why not get rid of it, thinking that at some point I must have put it there by mistake. But then I realized, maybe it's being used by Dropbox or GitHub or something like that. Is there a good reason why there might be a .git repository on your desktop (the size of the folder was a couple gigs, which is very strange). If I put it there by accident, then it doesn't need to be there. But are there any known applications that put the .git repo there on your desktop?

For now I am just going to rename the .git folder to see if anything breaks...

Comment: First use `git status` to see what is the status.

Comment: I sure hope Dropbox doesn't use git. A git repo that large suggests something is tracking changes to binary files like images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.git` folder is for Git repositories,
any program that would put a Git repository on your Desktop would be a very badly behaving citizen.
Most probably you created the repo yourself and forgot about it.

Open Git Bash, `cd` to your Desktop and run a couple of commands to see what's in the repository:

```
git status
git ls-files | less
git log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not see any breaks until you use that repository.

There must be a `.config` file in the `.git` folder, open it and you would see the priorities of this repository, including `remote origin` and `branch master`, etc.